# What does explicitly & implicitly mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I often see the terms explicitly & implicitly used in JavaScript and I'm still not sure I know what they mean i.e the following text from the MDC site describing the object model.

> The constructor function explicitly
>   sets the value of the projects
>   property, and implicitly sets the
>   value of the internal `__proto__`
>   property to the value of
>   `WorkerBee.prototype`...

[[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#Inheriting_properties)]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"Implicitly" means that the JS engine does it. "Explicitly" means that you must do it.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the kind of answer I was looking for but couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: @Nick – You can see this in the constructor: `function WorkerBee () { this.projects = []; }`

Comment: Or rather you *can't* see it, since it's *implicit*.

Comment: I meant the explicit setting.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of coercion in JavaScript: Implicit Coercion: Type conversion is done implicitly by JavaScript. Explicit Coercion: Type conversion is done explicitly in code using the inbuilt functions like Number(), String(), Boolean(), etc.